# PHP Notice : Undefined property

Tags: php, class

Here's a php class.

```
class WADB{
    private $sDbHost;
    private $sDbName;
    private $sDbUser;
    private $sDbPwd;
    private $iNoOfRecords;
    private $oQueryResult;
    private $aSelectRecords;
    private $aArrRec;
    private $bInsertRecords;
    private $iInsertRecId;

    function __construct($sDbHost, $sDbName, $sDbUser, $sDbPwd){
        // link to DB...
    }

    function selectRecords ($sSqlQuery){
        unset($this->aSelectRecords);
        $this->oQueryResult = mysql_query($sSqlQuery) or die(mysql_error());
        $this->iNoOfRecords = mysql_num_rows($this->oQueryResult);
        if ($this->iNoOfRecords > 0) {
            while ($oRow = mysql_fetch_array($this->oQueryResult,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $this->aSelectRecords[] = $oRow;
            }
            mysql_free_result($this->oQueryResult);
        }
        $this->aArrRec = $this->aSelectRecords;
        return array(   'data'      => $this->aArrRec,
                        'record'    => $this->iNoOfRecords);
    }
}
```

And This is how I use it :

```
require_once('WADB.php');
$db = new WADB('{HOST}','{DB_NAME}','{User}','{Password');    
$s1 = "SELECT * FROM {TableName} WHERE UserId='$_POST[UserId]';";
$d1 = $db->selectRecords($s1);
```

It didn't show the notice before as I used it, but now it shows

> **Notice**:  Undefined property: WADB::$aSelectRecords in **{my_computer_url}\WADB.php** on line **31**

line 31 is :

```
$this->aArrRec = $this->aSelectRecords;
```

It didn't show before as I used it.
I don't know why..?!

--

Sorry for my poor English, and hope you'll understand what I mean. ='(

Comment: Have you tried to remove `unset($this->aSelectRecords);`? And start using `mysqli_*` because `mysql_*` is depracted and will be removed

Comment: @SuperDJ Thank you for your advice!! I'll try to use `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `selectRecords` method, you have this: `unset($this->aSelectRecords);`, which effectively unsets the `aSelectRecords` data member. So, when you try to access the data later, it is not longer 'available'. 
If what you are trying to do is to empty the array this variable holds, then don't use `unset`, rather do this:

```
$this->aSelectRecords= array();
```

So you'd define the method as:

```
function selectRecords ($sSqlQuery){
    $this->aSelectRecords = array(); //rather than `unset`
    $this->oQueryResult = mysql_query($sSqlQuery) or die(mysql_error());
    $this->iNoOfRecords = mysql_num_rows($this->oQueryResult);
    if ($this->iNoOfRecords > 0) {
        while ($oRow = mysql_fetch_array($this->oQueryResult,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $this->aSelectRecords[] = $oRow;
        }
        mysql_free_result($this->oQueryResult);
    }
    $this->aArrRec = $this->aSelectRecords;
    return array(   'data'      => $this->aArrRec,
                    'record'    => $this->iNoOfRecords);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you make unset of proprety `unset($this->aSelectRecords);`
After this move you  have `if()` and if `if(false)`
you try to get value of this proprety but his unset
and you get error.